# How can I insert a double quote in the session relevance

Tags: relevance

```
target fixlet name = abcdef"123"
```

Then how can I use the session relevance to get the record?

Name of fixlet contains `"abcdef"123""` <<  doesn't work.

BTW DONT TRY TO EDIT ANYMORE, THIS IS NOT RELEVANT TO JAVA

IF YOU DONT KNOW WHAT IS SESSION RELEVANCE, PLEASE JUST SKIP THIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IBM relevance](http://support.bigfix.com/labs/relevanceeditor.html)

Since you are outputting to the Web as HTML I guess you have to encode them into **UTF-8**.

Double quote is `%22`, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), so try: `"adcdef%22123%22"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping quotes with backslash?

Comment: Error: This expression contained a character which is not allowed